# Why is my dictionary empty?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Newbie question again. 
I'm getting pairs of information from several URL, get from BS4 &URLlib
I create a list of list of list of Pair.
E.g : a pair for a couple (name,value)
E.g : a list of pairs for One URL
E.g : a list of list of pairs to be able to classify everything i got in a dictionary.

A list of list of pairs that should look like this :

```
List_of_list_of_pairs = [ [ [a,1],[c,2],[e,3] ], [ [g,4],[r,6] ... ], ... ]
```

Here is  the code i'm using :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request
from collections import *


def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  ##We use here ";" to parse CSV because of the European way of dealing with excel-csv
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data

List_of_list_of_pairs=[]
List_of_pairs=[]

list_url=parse_csv(open('url.csv','rU').read())




for i in range(0,len(list_url)) :

    url=str(list_url[i][0]) ## read URL from an array coming from an Url-CSV
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup_0 = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
    restricted_webpage= soup_0.find( "div", {"id":"ingredients"} )
    readable_restricted=str(restricted_webpage)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(readable_restricted,"html.parser")


    trs = soup.find_all('tr')

    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all("td")

        try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
            Nutriments = str(tds[0].get_text().strip())
            print(Nutriments)
        # This structure $isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
            Quantity = str(tds[1].get_text().strip())
            print(Quantity)
            Pair=[Nutriments,Quantity]
            List_of_pairs.append(Pair)

        except:
            print ("bad tr string")
            continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
List_of_list_of_pairs.append([List_of_pairs])

print(List_of_list_of_pairs)
dico = defaultdict(list)

for n,list_of_pairs in enumerate(List_of_list_of_pairs):
    for i,pairs in enumerate(list_of_pairs):
        if (len(pairs) == 2):
             cle = pairs[0]
             val = pairs[1]
             while (len(dico[cle]) < n):
                   dico[cle].append(-1)
             dico[cle].append(val)
for cle in dico:
    while (len(dico[cle]) < len(List_of_list_of_pairs)):
            dico[cle].append(-1)
print(dico.items())
```

Problem : `dico.items()` return something empty.

I fear that my list of list of pairs is not being well read. 
Maybe is it badly built. 
Something draw my attention. The number of "[" and "]" at the beginning and at the end of a list.  I think that's way to many.

That is the result of a `print(list_of_list_pairs)` :

```
[[['Cendres brutes (%)', '7.4'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.6'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '6.6'],..., [[['Cendres brutes (%)', '7.4'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.6'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '6.6'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '16.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '3.1'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3652.5'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3900.0'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'] ['Arginine (%)', '1.54'], ['L-lysine (%)', '1.15']]], [[['Cendres brutes (%)', '7.4']..
```

.

I think this is wrong. Some name like `Cendres brutes (%)` can appear only 3 times in this list (because there is one in each URL). I think something's wrong. 
But that doesn't explain why is my dic empty. 
Or maybe is it related.

Any help is most welcomed !

UPDATE : What i'm trying to do is :  from unorganized pairs of informations scrapped from several URLS , get an organized csv that looks like this :

```
NameKey ValURL1 ValURL2 ValURL3
 a        2.4     5.6    -1
 b         1.2     4.2    -1
 c        -1        -1    val
....
```

a,b,c ...  being what you can read like "Cendres Brutes" , "Acide Linoléique" ...

UPDATE : `print(List_of_list_of_pairs)` returns :

```
[[[['Cendres brutes (%)', '7.4'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.6'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '6.6'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '16.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '3.1'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3652.5'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3900.0'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '40.5'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '3.18'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '25.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '35.5'], ['Chlore (%)', '1.43'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '2.9'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '167.0'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '68.0'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '242.0'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '3.13'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '1600.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '13.9'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '32000.0'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '27.5'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '49.6'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '490.0'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '147.8'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '77.1'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '200.0'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.53'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '1.18'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '2900.0'], ['Acide arachidonique (%)', '0.07'], ['Cendres brutes (%)', '6.1'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '2.92'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '11.0'], ['DL-méthionine (%)', '0.5'], ['EPA/DHA (%)', '0.3'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '12.0'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '3.7'], ['Chlorure de glucosamine (mg/kg)', '495.0'], ['Glucosamine plus chondroïtine (mg/kg)', '500.0'], ['L-carnitine (mg/kg)', '100.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '2.42'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3425.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3584.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '0.92'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '41.7'], ['Oméga 3 (%)', '0.64'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '2.66'], ['Phosphore (%)', '0.7'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '27.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '34.4'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '3500.0'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '29000.0'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '300.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Calcium (%)', '0.9'], ['Polyphénols de thé vert et de raisins (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Chlore (%)', '0.63'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '4.8'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '212.0'], ['Magnésium (%)', '0.08'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '71.0'], ['Potassium (%)', '0.7'], ['Sélénium (mg/kg)', '0.29'], ['Sodium (%)', '0.4'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '201.0'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '2200.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '12.9'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '25.7'], ['Vitamine B12 Cyanocobalamine (mg/kg)', '0.13'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '46.2'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '458.7'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '137.9'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '72.0'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.52'], ['L-lysine (%)', '1.08'], ['Acide arachidonique (%)', '0.07'], ['Cendres brutes (%)', '5.9'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '3.07'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '7.0'], ['DL-méthionine (%)', '0.65'], ['EPA/DHA (%)', '0.3'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '16.0'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.3'], ['Chlorure de glucosamine (mg/kg)', '495.0'], ['Glucosamine plus chondroïtine (mg/kg)', '500.0'], ['L-carnitine (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '2.88'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3716.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3964.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '1.15'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '37.3'], ['Oméga 3 (%)', '0.63'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '3.13'], ['Phosphore (%)', '0.6'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '30.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '31.6'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '2000.0'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '31000.0'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '300.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Calcium (%)', '0.89'], ['Polyphénols de thé vert et de raisins (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Chlore (%)', '0.68'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '4.8'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '200.0'], ['Magnésium (%)', '0.12'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '73.0'], ['Potassium (%)', '0.65'], ['Sélénium (mg/kg)', '0.27'], ['Sodium (%)', '0.4'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '205.0'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '2400.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '13.6'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '26.9'], ['Vitamine B12 Cyanocobalamine (mg/kg)', '0.13'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '48.5'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '481.9'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '144.9'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '75.6'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.54'], ['L-lysine (%)', '1.15']]]]
```

UPDATE 2 : `print(List_of_list_of_pairs[0][0])` returns :

```
[['Cendres brutes (%)', '7.4'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.6'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '6.6'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '16.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '3.1'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3652.5'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3900.0'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '40.5'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '3.18'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '25.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '35.5'], ['Chlore (%)', '1.43'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '2.9'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '167.0'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '68.0'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '242.0'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '3.13'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '1600.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '13.9'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '32000.0'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '27.5'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '49.6'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '490.0'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '147.8'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '77.1'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '200.0'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.53'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '1.18'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '2900.0'], ['Acide arachidonique (%)', '0.07'], ['Cendres brutes (%)', '6.1'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '2.92'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '11.0'], ['DL-méthionine (%)', '0.5'], ['EPA/DHA (%)', '0.3'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '12.0'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '3.7'], ['Chlorure de glucosamine (mg/kg)', '495.0'], ['Glucosamine plus chondroïtine (mg/kg)', '500.0'], ['L-carnitine (mg/kg)', '100.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '2.42'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3425.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3584.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '0.92'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '41.7'], ['Oméga 3 (%)', '0.64'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '2.66'], ['Phosphore (%)', '0.7'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '27.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '34.4'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '3500.0'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '29000.0'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '300.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Calcium (%)', '0.9'], ['Polyphénols de thé vert et de raisins (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Chlore (%)', '0.63'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '4.8'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '212.0'], ['Magnésium (%)', '0.08'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '71.0'], ['Potassium (%)', '0.7'], ['Sélénium (mg/kg)', '0.29'], ['Sodium (%)', '0.4'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '201.0'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '2200.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '12.9'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '25.7'], ['Vitamine B12 Cyanocobalamine (mg/kg)', '0.13'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '46.2'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '458.7'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '137.9'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '72.0'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.52'], ['L-lysine (%)', '1.08'], ['Acide arachidonique (%)', '0.07'], ['Cendres brutes (%)', '5.9'], ['Biotine (mg/kg)', '3.07'], ['Fibres alimentaires (%)', '7.0'], ['DL-méthionine (%)', '0.65'], ['EPA/DHA (%)', '0.3'], ['Matière grasse (%)', '16.0'], ['Cellulose brute (%)', '1.3'], ['Chlorure de glucosamine (mg/kg)', '495.0'], ['Glucosamine plus chondroïtine (mg/kg)', '500.0'], ['L-carnitine (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Acide linoléique (%)', '2.88'], ['Lutéine (mg/kg)', '5.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (calculée selon NRC85) (kcal/kg)', '3716.0'], ['Energie métabolisable (mesurée) (kcal/kg)', '3964.0'], ['Méthionine Cystine (%)', '1.15'], ['Humidité (%)', '9.5'], ['Extrait non azoté (%)', '37.3'], ['Oméga 3 (%)', '0.63'], ['Oméga 6 (%)', '3.13'], ['Phosphore (%)', '0.6'], ['Protéine brute (%)', '30.0'], ['Amidon (%)', '31.6'], ['Taurine (mg/kg)', '2000.0'], ['Vitamine A (UI/kg)', '31000.0'], ['Vitamine C (mg/kg)', '300.0'], ['Vitamine E (mg/kg)', '600.0'], ['Calcium (%)', '0.89'], ['Polyphénols de thé vert et de raisins (mg/kg)', '150.0'], ['Chlore (%)', '0.68'], ['Cuivre (mg/kg)', '15.0'], ['Iode (mg/kg)', '4.8'], ['Fer (mg/kg)', '200.0'], ['Magnésium (%)', '0.12'], ['Manganèse (mg/kg)', '73.0'], ['Potassium (%)', '0.65'], ['Sélénium (mg/kg)', '0.27'], ['Sodium (%)', '0.4'], ['Zinc (mg/kg)', '205.0'], ['Choline (mg/kg)', '2400.0'], ['Acide folique (mg/kg)', '13.6'], ['Vitamine B1 Thiamine (mg/kg)', '26.9'], ['Vitamine B12 Cyanocobalamine (mg/kg)', '0.13'], ['Vitamine B2 Riboflavine (mg/kg)', '48.5'], ['Vitamine B3 Niacine (mg/kg)', '481.9'], ['Vitamine B5 Acide pantothénique (mg/kg)', '144.9'], ['Vitamine B6 Pyridoxine (mg/kg)', '75.6'], ['Vitamine D3 (UI/kg)', '800.0'], ['Arginine (%)', '1.54'], ['L-lysine (%)', '1.15']]
```

It seems that list_of_list_of_paris is badly built. I don't understand why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have a list of list of pairs, `List_of_list_of_pairs[n]` would still be the list of pairs, it will not be the pairs.

But your code is assuming that `List_of_list_of_pairs[n]` is the pair , which it isn't. You should iterate over first `List_of_list_of_pairs` and then the elements in it (which are List of pairs) and then try to add them to the dictionary.

Example -

```
for n,list_of_pairs in enumerate(List_of_list_of_pairs):
    for i,pairs in enumerate(list_of_pairs):
        if (len(pairs) == 2):
            cle = pairs[0]
            val = pairs[1]
            #Do the rest of your logic.
```

Also, you have this loop -

```
for cle in dico:
    while (len(dico[cle]) < len(s)):
            dico[cle].append(-1)
```

But I do not see `s` being defined anywhere, what is `s` supposed to be?

Comment: The dic is still empty. Thanks for your answer though !

Comment: What is the exact thing you are doing? Can you provide that as an update in answer (after changes I suggessted) .

Comment: The code has been updated ! Explanations have been added.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you should have changed the inner logic with respect to the changes in the loop definition.

Comment: s is the list of list of pair. It should be. Thank your for your answer. I updated the code.      `List_of_list_of_pairs.append([List_of_pairs])` shouldn't be in the big loop

Comment: It is still having issue?

Comment: Yes it is. I have clarified the 's' in the code. s=List_of_list_of_pairs in fact. But still is my dic empty.

Comment: Can you print and update the complete list_of_list_of_pairs[0][0] in the question.

Comment: Change this line - `List_of_list_of_pairs.append([List_of_pairs])` to - `List_of_list_of_pairs.append(List_of_pairs)` , and try

Comment: Clearly list_of_list_pairs[0][0] should return a pair [key,value]. EDIT : sorry, didn't see your answer ! I'm tryin'

Comment: Maybe its because you are adding `List_of_pairs` to `List_of_list_of_pairs` by enclosing them inside - `[]` . So it actually becomes `List_of_list_of_list_of_pairs` .

Comment: Thank you Anand S Kumar ! My code was supposed to get a -1 when the information didn't exist as i explained in the main post. Damn it ! . The `while` is being badly conditioned in a way or another because i can't see a -1 anywhere.

Comment: Do 2 more things, move this line - `List_of_list_of_pairs.append(List_of_pairs)` inside the for loop (the for loop in which you are reading the urls) . And then at the start of that for loop do - `List_of_pairs = []` .

Comment: Thanks A lot Anand ! Really. I just need to export it correctly. My `f=open('dict.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
for key,value in dico.items():
   writer.writerow([key, value])
f.close()
` It doesn't do the trick for now. It makes me a key;[value,value,value] where i want a key;value;value;value.

Comment: It works great. -1 in good place and everything'. The dictionary i wanted :)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to do that ! :)